# Split file name into substrings

Tags: string, vb.net, substring

I have a file name, from which I need to split and extract parts of the name for sorting it in a document register.

The files are typically of the following format:

> "1098-GT-0006-R0 Report Template.docx"

I need to split this string into the following three sections:

> Document Number: 1098-GT-0006
>
> Revision: 0
>
> Name: Report Template

What is the best way to achieve this in vb.NET?

The revision number could be anything from 0 to 20 (R0 - R20) and the first number, "1098" could be three, four or a five digit number.

Comment: First, I'd get the filename without the extension: [Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension(v=vs.110).aspx). Second, I'd look at the *actual* specification for the filename rather than consider a "typical" case. *Then* I could select an appropriate parsing method.

Comment: Look at using Regex to capture the groups of information. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your string format is fixed then below script may help you. this is not best solution to your problem but you could get idea to acheive desire result.

```
Private s As String = "1098-GT-0006-R0 Report Template.docx"
Private ss As String() = s.Split(" "c)
Private lastIndex As Int32 = ss(0).LastIndexOf("-"c)
Private DocumentNumber As String = ss(0).Substring(0, lastIndex)
Private Revision As String = ss(0).Substring(lastIndex + 2)
Private Name As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(String.Join(" ", ss(1), ss(2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jaydip Jadhav and a good suggestion from Andrew Morton, I managed to parse the file name as wanted. When I grab the file name first, I used:

```
Dim BigString As String = IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(<file path>)
```

Then I parsed the name as follows:

```
        Dim LeftS As String
        Dim lastIndex As Int32
        Dim DocumentNumber As String
        Dim Revision As String
        Dim DocName As String


        LeftS = BigString.Substring(0, BigString.IndexOf(" "))
        lastIndex = LeftS.LastIndexOf("-"c)
        DocumentNumber = LeftS.Substring(0, lastIndex)
        Revision = LeftS.Substring(lastIndex + 2)
        DocName = BigString.Substring(BigString.IndexOf(" ") + 1)
```

I would still be interested to see how this is done using Regex, if anyone thought it would be far better solution.